# ASP.NET MVC validation shows errors after loading a page

Tags: c#, jquery, validation, asp.net-mvc-5

ASP.NET MVC validation shows errors after loading a page (in ValidationSummary), I want to show it after click a "submit" button. My code is:

layout:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @RenderSection("head", required: false)
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    @RenderBody()

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

page:

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary()
....
}

@section Head {
    @Styles.Render("~/styles/jquery-ui-bootstrap-custom-theme")
}

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

bundle file has:

```
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));
```

Controller:

```
        public ActionResult VacancyForm(int? ID, VacancyFormViewModel model)
        {
            VacancyFormViewModel model = new VacancyFormViewModel();
....
            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: You need to show your controller methods

Comment: added, but what sense in controller?

Comment: Is that the GET or POST method? (if its the GET, then that's your problem!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have a parameter in a GET method which is a complex object (in your case `VacancyFormViewModel`). Apart from the ugly query string this creates;

1. if the model contains large number of properties, or properties with
   long values, it will exceed the query string limit and throw an
   exception;
2. if the model contains properties that are complex objects or
   collections, then binding will fail (internally a route value
   dictionary is generated based on the `ToString()` value of the
   property)

In your case, the `DefaultModelBinder` initializes a new instance of `VacancyFormViewModel` and sets the values of its properties (which may or may not succeed based on the above points). Because you have validation attributes on one or more of the properties, those errors are added to `ModelState` and therefore displayed in the form.

If the method is for creating a new `VacancyFormViewModel`,then just initialize a new instance of the model in the method. If its for editing an existing `VacancyFormViewModel`, pass the `ID` as a parameter and get the object from the repository based on the ID.